# Autocorrect on iOS doesn't fire onChangeText in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

react-native version : 0.43.4
Platform: iOS

Steps to reproduce:

1. Type a misspelled word in TextInput
2. Press space to make sure it haven't changed to the correct word yet. In case it did just delete and make it the misspelled word again.
3. Now iOS must be showing the word underlined with dotted red color. Tap on that and iOS will show you 2 types of autocorrect. One would be at the side of the word and second at the top of the keyboard.
4. Select the autocorrect from the top of the keyboard.
5. By checking logs etc you will know it hasn't fired any onChangeText event.

Any ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: So, what's your question?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone stumbling across this, the GitHub issue is here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2552

I thought of a temporary workaround while the issue is still open. Basically, in your `onSubmitEditing` callback, have it first call your `onChangeText` callback. If you had typed in "awrsome" and it was autocorrected to "awesome", `onChangeTextCallback` would have been called with "awesome".

```
onChangeTextCallback = (text) => { /* do stuff */ }
onSubmitEditingCallback = (e) => { /* do stuff */ }
```

And then in your JSX:

```
  <TextInput
    onChangeText = {onChangeTextCallback}
    onSubmitEditing = {(e) => {
      onChangeTextCallback(e.nativeEvent.text);
      onSubmitEditingCallback(e);
    }}
  />
```